# VB.Net Join SQL Connections

Tags: sql, vb.net, join

I have an SQL connection that connects to a server to bring back data.  I have been doing this to load the data into datatables.

I have created a query now that counts how many times a Location comes up for a given ID.  The query returns any ID that has a location count >1.

Now what I want to do is query the same source, but only return the IDs that were returned in the initial query, i.e. with a count of 2 or more.

This is more or less what my code for the counts looks like.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN
Table2
ON 
Table1.CAM = Table2.CAM
WHERE (pDate >= @pDate AND pDate <=@eDate)
AND ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM dbo.Exclude) 'Don't include these IDs
GROUP BY ID
HAVING (((COUNT(DISTINCT Location))>1))
```

Then the query that I normally use.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Location, Date
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN
Table2
ON 
Table1.CAM = Table2.CAM
WHERE (pDate >= @pDate AND pDate <=@eDate)
AND ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM dbo.Exclude) 'Don't include these IDs
```

Now, in the second query, I only want to return results that appeared in the first query.  Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not the exact query but should solve your issue. `EXISTS`

```
select ... -- this is your second query
from
table q2
where
exists   -- show row if the query below has at least a match
(
 select 1   --- this is your 1st query , 1 or * 
from table q1
where q1.ID = q2.ID    -- this will check if the ID in q1 is in q2 
)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am writing this in VB net.  First off, thanks for the response.  Secondly, I am a lot better with the VB than the SQL and I am confused on how to incorporate your answer with the code I posted.  You write 'from table q2'.  Would that come after my the entire block of code?  It would be super helpful if you could give an example with the code I posted.